# auto re-sizing iframe that dynamically changing height (smaller or bigger)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I know there's a lot of post about re-sizing `iframe` but all i found is this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<!--            
        function autoResize(id) {
            var newheight;
            var newwidth;

            if (document.getElementById) {
                newheight = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
                newwidth = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
            }
            document.getElementById(id).height = (newheight);
            document.getElementById(id).width = (newwidth);
        };
//-->
</script>
```

and this is the sample mark-up code:

```
<a href="index.php" target="content">Home</a>
<a href="profile.php" target="content">Profile</a>

<iframe src="index.php" name="content" height="500px" width="100%" id="Main_Content" onload="autoResize('Main_Content');"></iframe>
```

those codes above are working, but I have one problem. consider this scenario:

```
index.php page height is 800px
```

and

```
profile.php page height is 1200px
```

when i click on the link to `index.php` page, the iframe resizes to `800px`, and then I click the link to `profile.php` page and the `iframe` resizes to `1200px` BUT this is my problem, when I click again the link to `index.php` which is the height is smaller than the `profile.php` page, the `iframe` is not resizing and not adapting the `800px` height and it results in excess space below the content of the `index.php` which is not looking good, I do not have a problem on growing an iframe height but having some trouble on shrinking it,anyone can give me a hand? any help is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Is home.php the same as index.php?

Comment: oww, sorry for that, yes it is the same, just some typo.

Comment: And is the problem the same across browsers, or just for a specifc one?

Comment: same problem across browsers :(

Comment: can you please verify with an alert('hi'); in the autoresize function that IT is actually triggered the second time you click home? My best guess is that the onload event is not firing the second time.

Comment: i did what u said, i added an alert inside the autoresize function and  the alert is showing whenever i click the link for the index or profile, so i guess the onload event is firing, i edited my question and added some detail that my iframe has no problem on growing but having some trouble on shrinking in shorter heights.

Comment: I'll look at it in some more detail asap.

Comment: thanks sir, i'm looking forward to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
height: auto;
max-height: 1200px;
```

On the iframe itself within style="" or thru a css doc.

If height is set to auto, then it won't need to use the 1200px for the index.php. But when displaying the profile.php it's allowed to use a maximum of 1200px.

Comment: this doesnt work, and also the heights of the given pages is only a sample, it is a dynamic height, I do not have a problem on growing iframe sizes, but have a problem on shrinking.

Comment: Then you'll have to be more specific. Post it on jsfiddle. Setting a max height, still does help both ways. F.ex; set the max height to be the height of the page the iframe is displayed on and have overflow:scroll; set on the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the problem.

The problem seems to be the use of scrollHeight and scrollWidth which by intention return the current or needed space of the scrollbar, which is not equal to the size of the document itself.

The problem goes away for me when I change

```
 newheight = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
 newwidth = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
```

into

```
 newheight = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.style.height;
 newwidth = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.style.width;
```

is that doable for you, or is this not under your control?

Comment: hello kroonwijk, yes I can edit the script, I tried this but didn't solve my problem, thanks anyway for your effort