# load href to iframe but targetting it in parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have these codes:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Iframe</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <a href="somepage.html" target="content">SomePage</a><br/>
    <a href="anotherpage.html" target="content">AnotherPage</a><br/>
    <iframe src="" name="content" height="40%" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see I have two links and one iframe,What i need is when I click `SomePage.html` link, I want the `parent window` reloads and then the `SomePage.html` will be loaded in the `iframe`, is this possible?, Thanks!

**EDITED:**

I have an Auto-Resizing iframe that only grows on heights and cannot shrink to smaller heights (well that's my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337601/auto-re-sizing-iframe-that-dynamically-changing-height-smaller-or-bigger), All I want to achieve is the MasterPage like behavior in asp.net.

Comment: Why do you want to reload the parent window? what behaviour do you want to achieve?

Comment: Well im only thinking this as a solution in my problem here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337601/auto-re-sizing-iframe-that-dynamically-changing-height-smaller-or-bigger) because my autoresizing iframe is only growing its height and cannot shrink, So this idea comes in my mind but I don't even know if this is possible.

Comment: Why do you have an `<iframe>` in the first place. If you control the content, use a normal HTML element. If you don't there's nothing you can do due to [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: hello nietonfir, I understand what you are saying, but the code above is only a sample, I only make it simple for clarity of the question, but what I need is the stated in the question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, you can use `localStorage` it's not cross **fully** browser. Quick Example.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if(localStorage.frameURL) {
      $("iframe[name=content]").attr('src', localStorage.frameURL);
   }

   $("[target=content]").click(function() {
     localStorage.frameURL = $(this).attr('href');
     window.location.reload();
   });
});
```

Comment: hello sorry for this question but how does my anchor tag and iframe tag will look like? does the code remains like as I stated above?

Comment: hello Connor, thank you very much for this!, this solves my problem for over a week, by the way can I have another favor to you? Im not good at this, can I know how this local storage works? thanks!

Comment: Yeah, localStorage is like a mini database type thing that stores data on the client browser it will stay in the client database until the user clears the cookies and other site data from the browser.

Comment: No problem @JoeMarie feel free to join the [Javascript Chat Room](http://javascriptroom.com) whenever you feel.

Comment: ow there's a chat room, thanks for sharing that to me, i'm new here, thanks again sir!