# jQuery change size of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a function that change the size of the iframe every time a new content is loading.

It works fine, but there is a little problem:

If I open a big content the size change to it correct hight. If I load after that a smaller content, the height stays the same(from the big content), it isn't getting shorter.

I don't know why, how can I fix it?

```
$("#mainframe").load( function () {
  var c = (this.contentWindow || this.contentDocument);
  if (c.document) d = c.document;
  var ih = $(d).outerHeight() + 10;
  var iw = $(d).outerWidth();
  $(this).css({
    height: ih,
    width: iw
  });  
});
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for this?

Comment: Looks like this answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19339854/3388817

Comment: @problemPotato this dont work :/ and to keshu_vats, sry my english isnt that good dont know what do you want to say.